Was the Buddha neutral on self-centredness or selfishness?
In SN3:8 (Mallikā Sutta), when asked by King Pasenadi if there is anyone dearer to her than herself, Queen Mallika answered:

“No, great king. There is no one dearer to me than myself. And what about you, great king? Is there anyone dearer to you than yourself?”

Likewise, the King answered that he saw himself to be of utmost importance. When the Buddha was informed of this conversation, he affirmed that such is the case with all beings.
In our modern society, self-centredness (hereby termed as selfishness) has gotten a bad reputation while altruism (selfless concern for others) is widely celebrated. Therefore, I find it interesting and strange that the Buddha did not disapprove of the selfishness as expressed in the above sutra but only stressed that we should restrain from hurting others just as we would not want ourselves to be hurt i.e. norm of reciprocity.
Seeing that selfishness has a tendency to result in self-obsession as evident in this definition:

the state of being very focused on one’s own needs and well-being with a correspondingly decreased focus on the needs and well-being of others

Thus, my questions as below.

Why didn’t the Buddha disapprove of selfishness?
Isn’t selfishness a cause for people to hurt/harm others either intentionally/consciously or unintentionally/unconsciously.
Why didn’t the Buddha encourage his followers to “love thy neighbour as thyself”? Wouldn’t it help reduce self-obsession and potential problems in relationship due to selfish behaviour?
Could this be one possible cause for the philosophical difference between Theravada and Mahayana? Whereas the former is neutral on selfishness, the latter encourages compassion and pursuing enlightenment for the benefit of all beings.


These suttas: SN 3.8 and Ud 5.1 do not preach selfishness or self-centeredness.
Instead, they explain the basis of virtues and virtuous behavior, including the five precepts. A hint to this can be found in SN 55.7 and AN 5.57.

"What is the
purpose of skillful virtues? What is their reward?"
"Skillful virtues have freedom from remorse as their purpose, Ananda,
and freedom from remorse as their reward."
AN 11.1

Since the most dear person to everyone is themselves including you, the reader of this answer, we should not do unto others what we do not want others do unto us. This is called the Golden Rule.
This Golden Rule forms the basis of virtues. All of the five precepts can be explained in relation to the Golden Rule.
Some other religions depend on God to define the basis of virtues and morality, but Buddhism bases it on the Golden Rule.
The purpose of virtues is freedom from remorse. The rest of AN 11.1 explains how freedom from remorse leads to liberation.

Or it may be called the silver rule -- that distinction may be relevant to this topic.

The term 'selfishness' means:

Selfishness is being concerned excessively or exclusively for oneself or one's own advantage, pleasure, or welfare, regardless of others.
Wikpedia

The key term in SN 3.8 is 'piya', which appears to mean 'beloved' rather than 'selfishness'. A Pali term at times translated as 'selfishness' is 'macchara'.
For example, in the Attavagga of the Dhammapada, it is said:

Attānañce piyaṁ jaññā,
If one holds oneself dear,
one should diligently watch oneself.
rakkheyya naṁ surakkhitaṁ;
Attavagga

Thus SN 3.8 ends with the teaching:

“Having explored every quarter with the mind,
one finds no-one dearer than oneself.
Likewise for others, each holds themselves dear;
so one who cares for their own welfare would harm no other.”

The Buddha has taught what is in/for one's own interest/welfare is not harming others. Therefore, SN 3.8 is not about selfishness.
SN 55.7 also contains an equivalent love thy neighbour as thyself.

No, the Buddha didn't approve of hurting people or even imagining it. He didn't even approve of getting mad when someone else is hurting you (see the Simile of the Saw).
Selfish doesn't mean self interest, it means hurting others to get what you want. Of course everyone has self interest, it's not someone else's body and mind you have to live in. But there's no reason you have to hurt anyone in order to take care of your own needs.
In fact in a more normal society, i.e. an extended family unit/tribe, where everyone knows each other, hurting another member is hurting yourself, because you can't just skip town to avoid the consequences. Everyone knows what you did, and if you don't get straightened out, they may exile you, and unfortunately for you, the wolves that are going to eat you know how to get along and work together as the social creatures they are.
For the same reason, helping others helps you. It's why chimps are always picking ticks off each other, to reinforce social bonds. There's such a thing as a win win situation, you know. And you still don't have to bring the mystical side of karma into it at this point. If a society's members start preying on each other, the mentality and behavior spreads, people get angry and selfish, the society gets sick and may fail. Conversely, good behavior is also contagious. You know the saying "pay it forward", and "love begets love".

Why didn’t the Buddha encourage his followers to “love thy neighbour as thyself”? Wouldn’t it help reduce self-obsession and potential problems in relationship due to selfish behaviour?

Have you seen the teachings on metta, loving kindness? Yeah, it should reduce self obsession and destructive or abusive behavior. The suttas say it's impossible for ill will to keep overpowering the mind when metta is established. I think reducing self obsession is the main benefit of the Mahayana bodhisattva intention; it also goes with dana/generosity, it's as if you're giving away a bit of your own self importance and clinging, speaking of win win.

+1 indeed there exists enlightened self-interest or wise selfishness as expounded by the Dalai Lama. Perhaps, selfishness is not the same as selfish actions as it can lead to seemingly selfless actions too.

I just happened to see this relevant sutta today, that says practicing for your own sake is better than practicing for others, but the best is practicing for yourself AND others. -AN 4.95

Thanks a lot for pointing out this sutta! Although I am a bit puzzled why the Buddha put the person who practiced solely for themself higher than one who practiced solely for the sake of others. Perhaps, I will post a question on this.

Yeah, I wondered about that too. Maybe the implication is that if you're ONLY practicing for others, then it'll be in vain, because no one else can actually do their practice FOR them; and if you don't develop good qualities, etc. in yourself, then you can't set a good example for anyone else. But I'd be interested in hearing the real answer to that.

@Dan, is that similar to airplane instructions to put on your own oxygen mask first before putting one on a child or other seatmate?

Yeah, that'd be a good analogy. Or the one I've seen used is you can't save someone from drowning til you get yourself to safety (or become a stronger swimmer, and know the right way to do it without making the problem worse). I don't know if there's any deeper meaning to that part of the sutta, but from a practical standpoint, your practice only affects you. If it does affect anyone else, it's indirectly, from your mental state when they're around you.

So I suppose you could argue it's even a little dishonest, or at least unrealistic, to say you only practice for others. The attitude, not the practice itself; practice can't NOT help the one doing it. But it would be like taking medicine and hoping the other guy gets well. I don't know if that interpretation is what the sutta meant, but I don't think it would contradict it.


Why didn’t the Buddha disapprove of selfishness?

You define selfishness as self-centredness. Self-centredness is defined as being focused on one’s own interest even at the expense of others.
Essentially you are defining needs and wants as self. You are saying, needs are me , mine or myself. When needs as me , mine or myself arises self-centredness or selfishness arises. But Buddha says needs or wants are not me , mine or myself.
In other words needs or wants or craving are empty. Due to the presence of ignorance, needs , wants or cravings arise. This applies to all kinds of cravings. Cessation of craving is Nibbana.

Isn’t selfishness a cause for people to hurt/harm others either
intentionally/consciously or unintentionally/unconsciously.

Not selfishness but the ignorance is the cause for people to hurt or harm others.

Why didn’t the Buddha encourage his followers to “love thy neighbour
as thyself”? Wouldn’t it help reduce self-obsession and potential
problems in relationship due to selfish behaviour?

Love thy neighbour means neighbour is me , mine or myself. But Buddha says neighbour is not me , mine or myself. Feeling of love(or hate) arises depending upon the ignorance. Removing the ignorance is the only way to help others. How to remove ignorance? By keeping Four Nobel Truths in mind and following the Nobel Eight Fold Path.

Could this be one possible cause for the philosophical difference
between Theravada and Mahayana?Whereas the former is neutral on
selfishness, the latter encourages compassion and pursuing
enlightenment for the benefit of all beings.

I am learning Mahayana but I don’t think Theravada is weak on compassion. Theravada seems to be very conservative to me but they do not promote selfishness in any way other than practicing a selfishness which helps others. Save yourself first before saving others.
It is practically true that the most important person for laymen is themselves. But Buddha says if someone cuts your limbs or disembowls you alive then you should not have any cruel thoughts towards them. Buddha preaches extreme compassion. The greatest gift anyone can give to anyone is the Dhamma to remove ignorance.

Self-centredness or selfishness is a state of mind just as the brahmavihārā (sublime attitudes) of mettā, karuṇā, muditā and upekkhā. It may seem absurd to compare something so noble as the sublime attitudes with something so base as selfishness. But they are all states of the mind albeit at seemingly opposite spectrum.
As commented here, there are enlightened self-interest or wise selfishness as expounded by the Dalai Lama as we are all connected and interdependent in one way or another (paraphrased by me).
Indeed, selfishness appeared to be a double-edged sword. When combined with greed, aversion and delusion (as there are times when we either intentionally ignore or refuse to admit that our actions hurt others), it inflicts sufferings on others and ourselves. Yet when coupled with awareness and knowledge of karma, we can be motivated to take actions that improve the general well-being for all stakeholders i.e. I am doing good not just for others but for myself as well.

Perhaps, it is this recognition that all beings are self-centred in one way or another and that being self-centred is not the root cause of harm and suffering thus the Buddha did not disapprove of it. What is pivotal is the awareness of the consequences of our actions (with the underlying assumption that rational beings would NOT deliberately choose an action that is foreseen to invite bad repercussions).

As explained, selfishness is not a root cause of suffering.

Because even though we love ourselves deeply, we still act in silly ways that cause regrets in our lives. By logical extension, loving others too is NOT the ultimate solution to suffering. For example, the problem of doting parents with spoiled children. The Buddha never taught love is the answer to suffering. Instead as Ajahn Lee Dhammadharo once said in his talks, "The pursuit of heightened consciousness is the heart of the Buddhas' teaching."

Yes, I believe this is one of the main differences between both traditions. The Bodhisattva vow is not for the faint-hearted. It would not make sense if one is motivated purely by self-centredness or self-interest to go through such great trials and tribulations.



I will not accept any of my answers.
